# Newtonsoft.Json serialize datatable with MySqlDateTime

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I get a type of MySqlDateTime in a DataTable, which is select from MySql, just like 'select delivertime from t_storage', and then fill into a DataTable. Now I want convert this DataTable into json by Newtonsoft.Json, but it can not get the datetime, it's always convert null. Some code belows:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string sql = "select ig, gid, delivertime from t_storage";
MariadbHelper db = new MariadbHelper();// a dbhelper 
db.excute(sql).Fill(dt);// pull the sql result into dt
string ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);// the delivertime is null: [ {"id":1, "gid":1, "delivertime":null}]
```

I have tried use IsoDateTimeConverter to formate the date, but it does not work.

I am sure dt.Rows[0]["delivertime"] is a type of MySqlDateTime, and the value is not null. I can use '((MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime)dt.Rows[0]["delivertime"]).GetDateTime()' to convert it into DataTime type. In t_storage, the column delivertime is type of datetime.

Any idears?

Comment: What is the exact value of `ret` when the above code runs?

Comment: You need to check if there is data in the table and also if it is getting populated properly in `dt`.

Comment: the value of ret is like: {"id":1, "gid":1, "delivertime":null}

Comment: the value of ret is exactly as: [ {"id":1, "gid":1, "delivertime":null}], and i am sure dt.Rows[0]["delivertime"] is a type of MySqlDateTime, and the value is not null. I can use '((MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime)dt.Rows[0]["delivertime"]).GetDateTime()' to convert it into DataTime type.

Comment: `to convert it into DataTime type` What **specific** value do you get when you run that code?

Comment: it 's: "2018/5/24 16:45:58"

Answer (score 0):

The default format used by Json.NET is the `ISO 8601` standard: "2012-03-19T07:22Z". If you are getting a string in a different format then you can defined the `DateTimeFormat` of `IsoDateTimeConverter` while serializing. You can read about it [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm).

So define the Serialization logic as

```
string ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy/M/d H:m:ss" });
```

Comment: actually I tried but failed. I think the key point is the column type in DataTable is MySqlDateTime, not a string. I must call 'GetDateTime()' to get the DateTime type. Maybe json.net has no way to covert it automatically.

Comment: You can look for `JSonConverter` where you can write a serializing and deserializing logic based on your requirement.